# Can we add articles downloaded from Sci-Hub to a meta-analysis study?

Tags: publications, sci-hub, meta-analysis

Is it safe and legal to add articles downloaded from Sci-Hub to a meta-analysis study(unpublished)? Will it make any difference? Are there any consequences?

Comment: Are you intending a meta-analysis of Sci-Hub itself?

Comment: Based on the answers so far, you may need to clarify whether you discovered papers by searching SciHub, or just used it to access articles discovered in a structured search elsewhere. Many meta-studies use structured searches on sites like PubMed that often direct you offsite to access the full text of an article. A reviewer won't know (or ask) if it was accessed via SciHub or an institutional subscription service. But if you're searching SciHub and discovering articles there, you would report that in your study, and the legality/safety of using it would depend on the materials accessed.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your reply!

Comment: 1. If the study is done from home (due to COVID) hence, unable to get institutional access and 2. If a structured search is done in popular databases such as PubMed, Google Scholar, Scopus, etc., but unable to find a few open access articles, 3. if there's a narrow deadline; what is the best way to find full-text articles, to include in a meta-analysis study?

Answer (score 13):

If you disclose that you downloaded it from Sci-Hub, one cannot rule out that you will suffer legal consequences one day (alongside, perhaps, social punishments based on moral grounds). But given the almost non-existence of a legal enforcement against the individual use of this 'pirate', I find it unlikely.

To be on the safe side, you should simply *not* disclose the source from which you downloaded that publication. Mention it, discuss it, cite it, but do so without telling the reader how you acquired the PDF. This would be too much detail anyway.

(Yes, a meta-analysis would do good to disclose how it came to include certain studies, but it does not have to tell the reader in minute detail how you downloaded each study's PDF.)

Comment: On a fundamental level, science is (needs to be) reproducible. Obscuring how one acquired one's data makes it difficult for others to reproduce one's work, not to mention raises questions about how reliable the data is in the first place. -1

Comment: Hiding things seems to me to have ethical implications. Not disclosing things, for example.

Comment: @Allure How often do you encounter manuscripts mentioning how and where they accessed a given cited article? Excepting citations to rare historical manuscripts I find it incredibly rare to mention anything beyond what's contained in a standard citation. Do you also object to such citations, which generally say nothing abut which online repository or physical library was used to access a given article? I agree it's preferable to use an official source, in order to guarantee one's research is based on the official version of record, but that's a somewhat different matter to obfuscation.

Comment: @Allure In light of MikeyC's comment to the question, I should clarify that I assumed OP just downloaded articles from SciHub, rather than using SciHub as a search engine to identify articles to use for their metaanalysis. If SciHub is part of the methodology that should certainly be disclosed.

Comment: Disclosing the inclusion/exclusion criteria and what search systems were employed is essential to a metaanalysis. Disclosing where you got the PDFs from is not (it could be JSTOR, PMC, ScienceDirect, ILL, Journal Website, Sci-Hub, Email from the authors, Fax, Messenger Pigeon, or perhaps you just found it on the ground by chance). Nobody's ever bothered to include that information and if they did nobody would read it.

Comment: @Anyon I assumed the opposite side of MikeyC's comment, pretty much.

Answer (score -3):

No.

> Yet Sci-Hub has drawbacks for text-mining research, Hart-Davidson says. The pirated papers are in unstructured PDF format, which is hard for programs to parse. **But the bigger issue, he says, is that the data source is illegal. “How are you going to publish your work?”** Then again, having a massive private repository of papers does allow a researcher to rapidly test hypotheses before bothering with libraries at all. And it's all just a click away.

[Source](https://science.sciencemag.org/content/352/6285/508.full)

Comment: This may be a bit too strong. Not everything at Sci-Hub was uploaded illegally, breaking copyright. I think the site itself has an ethical issue, but not every person using it does if they take responsibility.

Answer (score -3):

One use of Sci-Hub is just laziness. There is a lot of stuff there that was put there illegally, but most of that stuff is also available from ethical sources. An academic librarian, for example, can get access to an enormous amount of stuff perfectly within copyright law. Perhaps it isn't so convenient, but no one will, at any time, question your ethics.

Some things can even be provided by their authors and/or publishers if it supports research.

There may be some expense, but grants can cover such things. Better, I think that you use only things ethically obtained.

Getting proper access also makes the question about reproducibility moot.

---

If I understand it correctly, some of the stuff on Sci-Hub was uploaded by authors perfectly legally and without copyright restriction. For such things, the source is immaterial.

Comment: People may have legal objections against Sci-Hub. But ethical? Really?

Comment: @Maeher, sorry, I don't understand. Are you suggesting use of Sci-Hub in general, is ethical? The legality is pretty much settled, I think.

Comment: `There may be some expense, but grants can cover such things. Better, I think that you use only things ethically obtained.` Agreed. Anyone who doesn't live in the US and have a grant shouldn't be allowed to have science. Filthy poors getting their disrespectful grubby little hands all over my clean journals.

Comment: @Libor, if you want a change then work for an ethical solution. First, find a way to finance the publishing system in a way that doesn't disadvantage people. The system we have isn't perfect, but nothing seems to be replacing it. Piracy is not the answer. But I expected this to be a downvote magnet. That doesn't make it wrong. But it does bring out the folks who don't much care about ethics. Or are willing to compromise themselves when convenient.

Comment: @Buffy I was agreeing with you. My only regret is that there are people from less developed countries like Canada or Europe who can read our comments here without paying for them as they should.

Comment: @Buffy Of course the use of Sci-Hub is ethical.

Comment: @Maeher, how about buying stolen televisions in a back alley? Same? You make no argument. The statement alone is just lazy.

Comment: @Libor I should hope you're not under the impression that subscription journals don't give out copious discounts to "Anyone who doesn't live in the US and have a grant".

Comment: @Buffy You are the one making the claim that something completely benign is unethical. The burden of proof for that extraordinary claim is on you. No party is hurt by the use of Sci-Hub, so what is your argument that it's use is in any way unethical?

Comment: @Maeher what do you mean it's completely benign? It breaks copyright law. You can't claim no party is hurt, since the copyright holder is hurt. Even if there really is nobody hurt, there are other things which hurt nobody that is nonetheless criminalized, e.g. incest.

Comment: @Allure You're confusing legality with ethics. Being illegal does not imply being unethical. And no, the copyright holder is not hurt. The author (who still hold the moral rights in my jurisdiction) still gets nothing. The publisher would not get a single cent more if any of the legal alternatives described here were used. Just because something beaches copyright does not mean damages actually occur. The only way the publisher could make any additional money would be if a person is clueless enough to buy the individual paper. And such a person wouldn't know about Sci-Hub to begin with.

Comment: @Maeher Two things. First, some people (like me) consider what is legal to be ethical, and what is illegal to be unethical. Second, if you truly believe the copyright holder is not hurt by piracy, you would also believe that copyright law is unnecessary. The fact that Pirate Parties worldwide have failed to be elected is a sign that that is a minority position.

Comment: @Allure that is an .... odd stance to take, considering how much laws differ between different jurisdictions, whereas ethics should largely remain the same. It's certainly not a mainstream view among jurists and I'm sure ethicists would strongly object. And no, it does not imply that copyright law is unnecessary (my own views on that are irrelevant). "Piracy" *can* cause actual financial damages, but in this specific case it does not.

Comment: @Maeher *ethics should largely remain the same* it doesn't in my view, and ethics vary by jurisdiction. You have probably heard of examples, e.g. whether it is ethical to breastfeed in public. As for the economic argument from piracy, that is a complicated topic (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_infringement#Economic_impact_of_copyright_infringement) so I will need evidence to believe that "in this specific case it does not".

Comment: As I've made my point clear, I will leave this pointless discussion here. Suffice to say that your views on ethics vs law are really "out there".

Comment: @Maeher or so you say. Do you have any statistics to back that up? You've already claimed in this specific case piracy does not cause financial damages, which is likely problematic by the way. For example, the reader could request the document from their library, which notes that the journal is in demand and therefore decides to subscribe to it. Are you aware libraries track denial statistics closely?